# How do I uninstall 'Command Line Tools for Xcode'

Tags: xcode, macos

Today Apple releases new developer tools, Xcode 4.3.

I installed 'Command Line Tools for Xcode - February 2012'.
BTW, How do I uninstall it?

I can't find uninstall-devtools.

You can get '[Command Line Tools for Xcode - February 2012](https://connect.apple.com/)'

Answer (score 2):

I created a shell script that removes the command line tools, see here: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/you-dont-need-the-xcode-command-line-tools/

(This uses the BOM receipt file for the CLI tools to remove all files that this installs)

My article explains why you don't need the CLI tools and how you can still use git or svn or any other tool that is contained in the Xcode.app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

- remove Xcode 4.3 from Applications by moving to the trash or using an uninstaller such as appzapper (if installed) (note: command line tools will still be installed at this point)
- install Xcode 4.2.1
- use the uninstaller to remove everything from 4.3 and 4.2.1:
  sudo /Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
- install Xcode 4.2.1 again