# How do I uninstall xcode 5 command line tools?

Tags: xcode5, uninstallation

I upgraded to xcode 5 Command Line Tools on Friday. Something is not working correctly and I want to go back to the last 4.x version ox xcode. How do I uninstall xcode 5 command line tools? I don't see anything in the release notes.

Comment: I ended up restoring a time machine backup. Everything was going wonky on my machine (RVM, xcode CLI, bundler) and after the restore, everything was much better. I must've messed something up badly. I would still like to know the answer to this question in case it comes up in the future.

Comment: Sorry, but I could not understand what you want exactly. Do you want to uninstall Xcode 5 and install a previous version? Or do you want to uninstall only the command line tools, keeping Xcode 5 with an older version of the command line tools?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756026/how-to-downgrade-xcode-to-previous-version

Comment: @PICyourBrain Did any of the answers actually help you? Did you find any other solution?

Answer (score 8):

Depending on whether you are running Xcode 5 in Mavericks or not, you will need to do two different things to uninstall the command line tools.

- In **Mavericks**, [Xcode includes its own copy of the Command line tools](http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/xcode-command-line-tools-included-with-xcode-5-0-x-on-mavericks/) (i.e. they are bundled as part of Xcode.app). Therefore, uninstalling the Xcode (check instructions below) will remove the Command line tools too.
- For **older Mac OSX versions** running Xcode 5 or older versions (Xcode 4.x), you can find **previous [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11446497/1264909)** which explain how to uninstall Xcode's command line tool. You can use this [script](https://gist.github.com/yoneken/3284561) (Read more about it in [this post](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/you-dont-need-the-xcode-command-line-tools/)):

  ```
  # remove_CLI_tools.sh
  # written by cocoanetics:http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/you-dont-need-the-xcode-command-line-tools/
  # modified by yoneken

  #!/bin/sh

  RECEIPT_FILE1=/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.DevSDK.bom
  RECEIPT_PLIST1=/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.DevSDK.plist
  RECEIPT_FILE2=/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.clang.bom
  RECEIPT_PLIST2=/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.clang.plist
  RECEIPT_FILE3=/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.llvm-gcc4.2.bom
  RECEIPT_PLIST3=/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.llvm-gcc4.2.plist
  RECEIPT_FILE4=/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI.bom
  RECEIPT_PLIST4=/var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI.plist

  if [ ! -f "$RECEIPT_FILE4" ]
  then
    echo "Command Line Tools not installed."
    exit 1
  fi

  echo "Command Line Tools installed, removing ..."

  # Need to be at root
  cd /

  # Remove files and dirs mentioned in the "Bill of Materials" (BOM)
  lsbom -fls $RECEIPT_FILE1 $RECEIPT_FILE2 $RECEIPT_FILE3 $RECEIPT_FILE4 | sudo xargs -I{} rm -r "{}"

  # remove the receipt
  sudo rm $RECEIPT_FILE1 $RECEIPT_FILE2 $RECEIPT_FILE3 $RECEIPT_FILE4

  # remove the plist
  sudo rm $RECEIPT_PLIST1 $RECEIPT_PLIST2 $RECEIPT_PLIST3 $RECEIPT_PLIST4

  echo "Done! Please restart XCode to have Command Line Tools appear as uninstalled."
  ```

You can **run this easily** by opening a Terminal and running this command (it will download the script and execute it automatically):

```
curl "https://gist.github.com/yoneken/3284561/raw/db665bb64f93e38ce138b5ca620b9edd18dc31e4/remove_CLI_tools.sh" | sh
```

If everything worked fine, you could open Xcode and see that the Command Line Tools appear as to be installed.

Then, depending on what you want, you could ***downgrade Xcode to a lower version and reinstall the Command Line Tools for that version***, for example.

To downgrade Xcode, as explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14756127/1264909):

1. Uninstall Xcode 5: go to `/Applications` and delete the Xcode app.
2. Restart the Mac.
3. Then you can download the desired Xcode version from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) and install it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that script doesn't work for XCode 5, as I understand it. It is for the 4.3 CLI

Comment: After some more research, I found that with **Xcode 5.0.x and Mavericks**, Apple has gone back to **bundling the Xcode command line tools for into Xcode.app** (+info: http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/xcode-command-line-tools-included-with-xcode-5-0-x-on-mavericks/). Therefore, unless you installed the Command line tools manually, uninstalling the app should remove the Command Line Tools too.

Comment: @WattsInABox Did my last research help you at all? I would like to verify that the answer is correct for your specific situation too.

Comment: That sounds very helpful so I gave you a +1. I don't actually need this right now b/c I worked around the problem, but it's a good tip. Thanks!

Comment: @veducm this is not the case with me on mountain line. still running gcc shows clang

Comment: @MuhammadAnnaqeeb How did you installed the Command Line Tools. Remember that in Mavericks, they come packaged with Xcode 5, but you can still install them separately. In case you install them manually or with an older version of Xcode, they won't get uninstalled automatically with Xcode, so you will need to uninstall them manually.

Comment: I installed it on mountain Lion from Xcode 5.0.2  Prefernce ->Downloads Tab , as described in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57974/cant-install-xcode-command-line-tools-on-mountain-lion when i removed Xcode 5 and restarted the mac they were not gone. if i run gcc in console, i get clang saying there is no input file. I had to run a script  from http://superuser.com/questions/638258/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-the-os-x-developer-tools to remove the command line tools. I wrote the script in the answer below.

Comment: @MuhammadAnnaqeeb So in your case (Xcode 5 in an older version of MacOS), that would be the second scenario stated in my answer, the given script did not work for you? Did you get any errors when running it? Because the script in your answer looks very similar to the one proposed in this answer for your situation, doesn't it?

Comment: The url has changed: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yoneken/3284561/raw/db665bb64f93e38ce138b5ca620b9edd18dc31e4/remove_CLI_tools.sh

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled upon this while trying to uninstall Command Line Tools v6.

I had the full Xcode 6 installed, but moving Xcode to trash did **NOT** uninstall/delete CLT as well. I still had `/usr/bin/clang` for example. The solution was to manually remove CLT using the .bom contents (similar to @veducm's answer):

```
cd /
lsbom -fls /var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables.bom | sudo xargs -I{} rm -rf "{}"
lsbom -fls /var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.DevSDK_OSX109.bom | sudo xargs -I{} rm -rf "{}"
sudo rm /var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.{CLTools_Executables,DevSDK_OSX109}.{bom,plist}
```

Replace `DevSDK_OSX109` with the version you have. You may have multiple ones, in which case, apply the same command to all of them (e.g. I had both `DevSDK_OSX109` and `DevSDK_OSX1010` because I had installed CLT for Mavericks and Yosemite too).

NOTE: This will delete the files listed in the .bom. You can view the contents them first by doing just `lsbom -fls /var/db/receipts/com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables.bom` etc if you are unsure.

NOTE2: You need the `cd /` since paths reported by lsbom are relative. You can also remove CLT by simply doing `rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`.

Answer (score 2):

The rm command removes (deletes) files or directories.

Delete CLT from following command

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

from terminal.