# I removed xcode, but "xcode-select --version" still shows me its version

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, command-line-tool

I have removed xcode from my Mac 10.9.3. I opened the Applications folder and dragged it to the trash (and emptied it).

But when I run the command `xcode-select --version`, I get:

```
xcode-select version 2003.
```

How is that possible? Does it mean xcode is not properly uninstalled?

Answer (score 2):

xcode-select is not part of the Xcode.app bundle.
It lives in /usr/bin/

You can check that via

```
whereis xcode-select
```

in Terminal.

Comment: It's located here: `/usr/bin/xcode-select` - what to do with it now?

Comment: I don't think that Apple provides anything to uninstall the CLI tools. There is a SO answer about this topic. Maybe you can find something there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635919/how-do-i-uninstall-xcode-5-command-line-tools