# How to uninstall the latest Xcode 6 CLI tools on OSX 10.9.5?

Tags: osx-mavericks, xcode6

I manually installed Xcode 6 CLI tools on OSX 10.9.5, but I want to install the whole Xcode now. How can I completely remove the CLI tools?

This script seems only for Xcode 4.x: [How do I uninstall xcode 5 command line tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635919/how-do-i-uninstall-xcode-5-command-line-tools)